# Early 2000s film, FBI-like agents investigate a deadly TV signal, which causes cells to "expel calcium", paralyzing people and making them shatterable

Tags: story-identification, movie

Film produced no later than 2005, with the following ridiculous premise:

A few people watching TV die due to apparent paralysis and suffocation.  One old man falls out of his chair and shatters on the floor.

Two absurdly attractive law enforcement agents (FBI?) investigate, track down cause to TV station/network with disgruntled techie who discovered way to embed deadly signal in broadcast, which causes humans' cells to 'expel calcium', somehow paralyzing them and causing them to be shatterable.  Agents stop the mad scientist from broadcasting signal on wide scale, save life of head of station/network, go all kissy face.

I saw this stupid, stupid, STUPID movie on Sci-Fi Channel before the name change to Syfy, somewhere between fall 2000 and spring 2005.  The male agent was played by one of those heartthrob Latino soap opera-esque actors from the late 90s and early 00s.

Comment: But was it in english?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Fatal Error* (1999)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_Error):

> A technological nightmare becomes a terrifying reality in this sci-fi-thriller. When a group of computer experts and executives from a high-tech firm based in Seattle die suddenly and unexpectedly during a conference call, Samantha Craig (Turner), a government agent who specializes in disease tracking, is brought in to investigate.
>
> Craig finds herself having to work alongside Dr. Nick Baldwin (Sabato), a local physician trying to live down a professional disgrace, and together they make a shocking discovery: a deranged programmer named Ned Henderson (David Lewis) has developed a computer virus that has evolved from destroying databases into an organic virus that can claim human lives. But how would he be able to create such a contagion, and how can it be stopped?

It's the answer to [this Yahoo thread](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131021123323AAObMCm) which was likely searching for the same movie:

> All I remember is two cops/FBI agents, one of whom may have been Lou Diamond Phillips or someone similar, trying to track down someone who created a TV signal that kills through a visual signal that causes human bodies to expel calcium through cell membranes and harden. Some victims fall over and shatter.

From the answer there, the resolution indeed consisted in stopping mass broadcasting:

> Samantha and Nick must then prevent Digicron's box being sold to the general public in vast numbers, according to the company's Barnum-marketing starting in only two days, but CEO Teal refuses to believe them.

The "heartthrob Latino soap opera-esque actor" would be [Antonio Sabàto Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Sab%C3%A0to_Jr.) who according to Wikipedia "first found fame in the 1990s, [...] appearing as Jagger Cates on the soap opera [*General Hospital*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Hospital) from 1992 to 1995".

---

Found with the Google query `movie cells expel calcium fbi` which returns the above Yahoo thread.

Comment: Bravo, bravo, BRA-FREAKING-VO!!!  That's some fantastic research in a short block of time, Jenayah.  Thanks ever so much.

Comment: @BobBob *blushes* thanks! Enjoy the rewatch, make sure to have one BIG bucket of popcorn, it seems mandatory for such a stupid-sounding flick :D

Comment: What makes this even funnier is why that question on Yahoo matches my write-up so well: I wrote it years ago, and completely forgot to ever look for an answer.  I am dead serious.

Comment: I particularly like the characterization of Antonio Sabato Jr. as "Lou Diamond Phillips or someone similar."